# How to preserve Search Engine Rank after domain change with 301 Redirect?

Tags: seo, domains, url, search-engines, 301-redirect

Before you mark this question a duplicate, read the question properly.
I have had a domain `http://muzic.asia` and because of low quality TLD it's SEO rankings were less (For some keywords it ranked even to the first position in Google). see this img: [image: danga maari mp3]
Since I learnt using a better Keyword & TLD in domain could boost the domain's SE visibility, I registered another domain: `http://fullsong.org`

I have learnt that a 301 permanent redirect could notify Search Engines about the domain change as suggested in hist post - [Preserve search engine rankings while shifting to new domain name](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/21720/preserve-search-engine-rankings-while-shifting-to-new-domain-name)
But here the issue is like this - [Rankings dropping after small URL-change WITH 301-redirect](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/37973/rankings-dropping-after-small-url-change-with-301-redirect)

Because most of the URL which are indexed in Google are like this:
`http://muzic.asia/music/view/10750720`
And I want to change the URL with the new domain as:
`http://fullsong.org/music/view/10750720?download=Goli-Maare-Tera-Dupatta`

So how do I redirect the domain. Should I redirect the domain only to the main page like `muzic.asia => fullsong.org` or redirect each URL to the new URL like
`http://muzic.asia/music/view/10750720 => http://fullsong.org/music/view/10750720?download=Goli-Maare-Tera-Dupatta` or should I submit every new URL to Google again?

Note: I do not have access to the .htaccess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to redirect every page to its specific version on the new domain.

If you just redirect the home page you will be left with loads of 404's in Google which wont pass over the SEO value, and if you redirect every page to the home page, your inner pages wont recieve the SEO value form the old URLs.

You also need to add both sites in [Google Search Console](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34592?hl=en), and [submit a change of address](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en&vid=1-635780788460443011-784166504)s in there to tell Google you have moved domains.

Also I would suggest against using URL parameters in your URLs, they aren't very Search Engine friendly. Also try not to use meaningless numbers.

A better URL would be something like:

```
http://fullsong.org/music/view/goli-maare-tera-dupatta-mp3/
```

Or even better:

```
http://fullsong.org/music/download/goli-maare-tera-dupatta-mp3/
```